# Dark spot on Asus laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

Several weeks ago a darker spot appeared on my screen (as seen in the attached picture, it's right under the "Super User" tab) and it looks as if there was some liquid behind the screen.

When I physically press it, it doesn't change its shape and it didn't change its shape since it appeared (around 2 weeks ago).

The spot is visible especially on white background and is very weak with black background.

[image]

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That type of spot is in the screen, itself.  It's hard to tell definitively what it is from the picture.

- It could be a spot where something pressed against the screen and created a thin area in the liquid crystal layer.  That type of spot usually has a diffuse edge.  There's nothing you can do to fix it, but it might lessen over time by itself.
- It could be a bubble, where one layer of the screen separates from the layer behind it.  Those tend to look like a bubble, with a well-defined outline (hard to tell from the picture).  They are more likely to happen at an edge.  There's equipment to fix that in a small screen, like a cellphone, but I'm not aware that's it's repairable on a monitor-sized screen (and none of the home remedies on the Internet will fix that).
- If it extends to the edge of the screen it could potentially be a drop of liquid that wicked between the layers (hard to see the top boundary in the picture).  That will have a well-defined edge.  If no liquid has ever been near it, you can rule that out.  There's no fix for that.
- It could be a surface stain on the outside of the glass, which could be cleaned.  That should be more visible if you shine a light on it at an angle so you can see a good reflection on the glass.

Other than an exterior stain, there isn't anything you can do to fix any of the other things it could be (other than invest a lot of money to replace the screen).  As long as the screen still works, the practical solution is to just live with it and don't let its presence bug you.  Revel in the thought of all the money you will save by not replacing the screen.  Don't try to "fix it", you can only make it worse.